# Grav CMS home_url with anchor

Tags: twig, grav

So, I want to add some anchor to my url. My code

```
<a href="{{ home_url }}/#anchor">Link name</a>
```

and it's not working. It gives me something like this

```
<a href="//#anchor">Link name</a>
```

what I want is

```
<a href="mydomain.com/#anchor">Link name </a>
```

How can I do that? Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `{{ base_url }}` instead of `{{ home_url }}`. [Grav's documentation of theme variables](https://learn.getgrav.org/themes/theme-vars) says this:

> **base_url variable**
>
> The `{{ base_url }}` returns the base URL to the Grav site, whether or
>   not this shows the full URL is dependent on the `absolute_urls`
>   [option in the system configuration](https://learn.getgrav.org/basics/grav-configuration#system-configuration).